# strange stun protocol detected by wireshark

Tags: protocols, wireshark, stun

i have win7 operating system without any services or program sending stream at background,firewall inbound connection set to none, sharing disabled, and i am behind NAT. Today i just start wireshark, then i see these STUN protocols, i cannot find any process send the stream because the stream doesn't show in resmon,taskmgr,or processhacker.

below is the screenshot of wireshark
[image]

how to see which program/service which sending/accept STUN protocols ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STUN is Session Traversal Utilities for NAT. Originally designed for VOIP apps.

Something is using it on your Windows, and I would scan for malware/viruses as those have been known to use STUN as an exploit:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN

http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2014/09/malware-trending-stun-awareness/